# Proof Formalization Regarding Limit of a Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> If a sequence $a_n$ of positive integers takes on each possible value only finitely many times, show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$$

I understand what the problem asks and have a general concept for how to prove it, but no concrete, formal expression of a proof. My pseudo-proof runs along the following lines: if for each $k$, $a_n=k$ for only finitely many $n$, then there exist elements greater than $k,\forall k$. Then, because [SOME REASON] there exist infinitely many values where $\frac{a_n}{n}>$(some positive, increasing function of $n$), so $a_n>n$(the earlier function), so there are infinitely many values at which $a_n>a_{n-i}\forall i$, so the set of those elements, a subsequence of the overall sequence, tends to $\infty$. That should be somehow sufficient to show that the entire sequence also must grow without bound.

Anything you could suggest regarding formalizing this proof (or, if I'm wrong, showing its incorrectness and suggesting a different proof) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let $n\in\Bbb Z^+$; $\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:a_k\le n\}$ is finite, so there is a $k_n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $a_k>n$ whenever $k\ge k_n$. This is exactly what it means to say that $\lim_ka_k=\infty$. If you want to give a little more detail, you could explain why $\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:a_k\le n\}$ is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $a_n\not\to \infty$. Then there exists an integer $M>0$ such that $a_n\le M$ infinitely often. In particular $a_n$ takes on one of the values $1, \dotsc, M$ infinitely often. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I see some weakness of your proof in speaking about subsequence, while task requires limit.

Let me suggest following hint: for any $M \in \mathbb{N}$ only finite members or $a_n$ can be less or equal to $M$. So $\exists N\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $a_n > M$ for $\forall n>N$.